# Module not found: Can't resolve 'v8' In NextJS with Twin Macro

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am getting `Module not found: Can't resolve 'v8'` while using the package in Nextjs with Typescript.

If I use `.js` file, then it's working fine, If I use  `.tsx` file then it throws `Module Not found` error. Even after installing this package, Further packages start reporting issues of missing.

Here's very simple code block which I am using and still it's not working.

```js
import tw from 'twin.macro';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const Container = tw.div`relative bg-gray-200 -mx-8 -mb-8 px-8`;
  return (
    <div>Hey Buddy</div>
  )
}
```

#### Here's the package info -

```json
"next": "14.0.0",
"react": "18.0.0",
"twin.macro": "^3.4.0"
"tailwindcss": "^3.0.0",
"typescript": "^5"
```

#### Here's withTwin config -

```js
const path = require('path');

const includedDirs = [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')];

module.exports = function withTwin(nextConfig) {
  return {
    ...nextConfig,
    webpack(config, options) {
      const { dev, isServer } = options;
      // Make the loader work with the new app directory
      const patchedDefaultLoaders = options.defaultLoaders.babel;
      patchedDefaultLoaders.options.hasServerComponents = true;
      patchedDefaultLoaders.options.hasReactRefresh = false;

      config.module = config.module || {};
      config.module.rules = config.module.rules || [];
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        include: includedDirs,
        use: [
          patchedDefaultLoaders,
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMaps: dev,
              plugins: [
                require.resolve('babel-plugin-macros'),
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-plugin-styled-components'),
                  { ssr: true, displayName: true },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      });

      if (!isServer) {
        config.resolve.fallback = {
          ...(config.resolve.fallback || {}),
          fs: false,
          module: false,
          path: false,
          os: false,
          crypto: false,
        };
      }

      if (typeof nextConfig.webpack === 'function') {
        return nextConfig.webpack(config, options);
      } else {
        return config;
      }
    },
  };
};
```

#### Here's the issue I am facing -

[image]

I want Tailwind css to be working in NextJS for Serer Side rendering. Also I want with Typescript. I tried installing v8 package but that throws further errors